# "Offline for maintenance" error message shows incorrect site name

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

A short while ago, this site was down for maintenance.

However, the error page shown during said maintenance period incorrectly stated the name of this site:

> [image: Math Overflow is currently offline for maintenance]

As you probably know, this site is actually called "MathOverflow". Can this please be fixed?

(Note that unlike the `/error` page, it's not possible to see this error page unless the site is actually down for maintenance.)

(Also, I cannot find any relevant tags other than the required tag for this question - can someone please add in or create the right tag?)

Comment: Related: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2993/454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just written a message to the Stack Exchange Team, and asked them to respond to this here. History has shown that this could take at least a few days.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Of course, you'll have to wait for the next outage to confirm...

Comment: Thank you, Shog9.