# Should there be a banner with some basic info about MO in the right sidebar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users, sidebar

A recent discussion about [customizing the "Draft your question" panel](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5774) reminded me of an older one here: [Feature request: add short "about MathOverflow" section to the front page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5260).
In an answer to that question, I mentioned that it is possible to have a short banner about the site in the right sidebar.

At least we can definitely say for sure that this was customized on several sites, a few are listed here: [Which elements of the frontpage can be customized per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378042). So this is something which is technically possible.

As an illustration, I will include the screenshots from [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/) or [Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/). You can also find the discussions which led to adding the banner [on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1125) and [on Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5952).

So I wanted to ask:

- Do you think that it could be useful to a have similar banner on this site - with a brief explanation what MathOverflow is and that it isn't a site for all mathematical questions?
- If you think something like this should be added, what wording would you suggest for this banner?

---

I am aware that probably will not help too much, things like this are easy to ignore. After all, new users are already shown various recommendations [before asking the first question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5007).

But since Thomas Kojar brought somewhat related suggestion [not too long ago](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5774) about including some text next to the edit window, perhaps discussing this at the same time is reasonable - after all, the purpose of both suggestions is similar, to some extent.

---

Here is a screenshot from Law Stack Exchange:

[image: screenshot with the banner]

And also from Medical Sciences:

[image: screenshot shown the banner in the sidebar]

Answer (score 11):

Here is one possible suggestion what the text in the banner could look like - it is based on the first bullet point from the text [displayed to the first-time askers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5073).

> MathOverflow is a site for questions about [research-level mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic). Use [other sites](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3760) for general mathematical questions.

We should probably keep the text relatively short - it takes space in the right sidebar, other things are displayed there too. Moreover, the other bullet points from the modal window are relevant only for somebody who is actually posting a question here - this short text could at least provide a link to the part of the help center explaining what is on topic here.

Comment: I would even add "... about research-level mathematics for professional mathematicians."  (Even if it is not strictly the case, we should still add it to discourage poor quality questions.)

Comment: @PatrickR A risk with adding such a note is that it could discourage PhD students from asking questions (and those are often good!). It could also discourage amateur mathematicians.